# how to set swift var closure

Tags: xcode, swift

I have this variable:

```
var udpCallback: ((data:NSData) -> Void)?
```

I set it thusly:

```
Udp.sharedInstance.udpCallback = { (data:NSData) -> Void in
        Audio.sharedInstance.play(data)
}
```

I get the error

> Cannot assign a value of type '(NSData) -> Void' to a value of type '((data: NSData) -> Void)?'

It doesn't help if I remove the optional "?". How can I fix this error?

This is in Xcode 7.0 beta.

Comment: Your code works fine for me.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: After removing `Udp.sharedInstance.` and replacing `Audio.sharedInstance.play(data)` with a print statement, it works fine for me in Xcode 7 beta 4. You may want to try deleting derived data.

Comment: I suspect the fix was to upgrade to beta4.

Comment: Is `Audio.sharedInstance.play()` expecting an NSData object?

Comment: Yes, the problem was Xcode 7 beta v1